# Is it possible to calculate the mode of a column in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am working on a query to perform aggregations on a few columns in one of my tables on BigQuery. For part of this query, I want to be able to calculate the mode of a couple of the columns but I can't find a method for doing so natively in the query. Is this possible or do I need to process the query results in an external script to get those results?

Answer (score 4):

// mode is the item that occurs most frequently in a group

```
SELECT TOP(column, 1) AS mode, COUNT(*) AS freq
FROM dataset.table
```

> to follow up on Felipe's comment, see below version using group by

```
SELECT column AS mode, COUNT(1) AS freq
FROM dataset.table 
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Depends on your use-case - there are still some issues might need be addressed, like *tie* for example

Comment: Just have in mind that TOP() is fast, but approximate. For exact results GROUP BY.

Comment: Thank you Felipe! Yes, it is clearly stated in documentation